# Android Upload Video to Server using PHP. Error: failure delivering result to activity

Tags: java, php, android, video

I am a beginner. I want upload video to the server. A simple sample: [Android Upload Video to Server using PHP](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-video-to-server-using-php/)

I am trying to use the following in my project:

uploadvideo.php

```
        <?php

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
     $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

     $location = "http://localhost/android/upload/";

     move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$file_name);
     echo "http://localhost/android/upload/".$file_name;
     }else{
     echo "Error";
     }
     ?>
```

upload.java

```
    public class Upload {

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL= "http://10.0.3.2:90/android/uploadvideo.php";

    private int serverResponseCode;

    public String uploadVideo(String file) {

        String fileName = file;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        File sourceFile = new File(file);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
            return null;
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", fileName);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                        .getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }else {
            return "Could not upload";
        }
    }
}
```

sendvideo.java

```
    public class Sendvideo extends Fragment  {

    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 2;
    String selectedPath = "";

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:90/android/uploadimage.php";

    public static final String KEY_NAME= "TEN";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE= "HINH";

    LinearLayout ll;
    EditText et_sendvideotitle;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendvideo, container, false);

        Button btn_choosevideo = (Button)ll.findViewById(R.id.btn_choosevideo);
        Button btn_sendvideo = (Button)ll.findViewById(R.id.btn_sendvideo);
        et_sendvideotitle = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_sendvideotitle);
        EditText et_sendvideodesc = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_sendvideodesc);

            btn_choosevideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openGalleryVideo();
                }
            });

        btn_sendvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadVideo();
            }
        });


        return ll;
    }

    // *********************************************************************************

    public void openGalleryVideo(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select vid"), SELECT_VIDEO);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
                Log.i("data.getDataString() ",data.getDataString());
                Uri selectedfile = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedfile);
                System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO Path : " + selectedPath);

        }
    }


    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        Log.i("cursor.toString() ",cursor.toString());

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }


    private void uploadVideo() {
        class UploadVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog uploading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                uploading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "up", "...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                uploading.dismiss();
                et_sendvideotitle.setText(Html.fromHtml("Uploaded at <a href='" + s + "'>" + s + "</a>"));
                et_sendvideotitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Upload u = new Upload();
                String msg = u.uploadVideo(selectedPath);
                return msg;
            }
        }
        UploadVideo uv = new UploadVideo();
        uv.execute();
    }


}
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/titraj_176034.mp4 }} to activity {xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxxx/xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.Drawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> On line:   Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
>           Log.i("cursor.toString() ",cursor.toString());

Please help me!

Comment: So you have a NullPointerException as you use a variable thats null. Which variable is null?

Comment: I tested it by small videos (less than 5MB), and some extensions (like .3gp .mp4 and etc). But no success! Failure delivering result and cursor is null.

Comment: If you cannot tell more about what is happening then how could we help? Please explain for what you need a cursor.

Comment: In run, when I click on btn_choosevideo and after selecting a video in Download directory in Emulator, it stops.In Manifest:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: `it stops.`. Well that is not enough info. Explain much more what happens and what not happens. And you did not answer my question. Very strange.

Comment: I want select video without error and after it, I want click on btn_send to upload it to the server. But, I have error "Unfortunately the process xx.xxx.xxxx has stopped" when I select a video (after click my video in GallaryVideo of Emulator ). There is error in pick video.

Comment: Sorry but you did not pass.

Comment: Excuse me, can you test my code?

Comment: Dont have to test it. Its pretty clear what goes wrong. I'm just waiting for you to tell exactly what goes wrong. And still waiting for an answer to my question. Your problem is posted every week on stackoverflow. You are number ### posting it. So with a little bit of reading this site you would long have found the culprit and the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a link for helping?